# Center an unordered list in a table

Tags: css, html-lists

I have code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <ul>
        <li style="float:left;display:inline">Some text</li>
        <li style="float:left;display:inline">Other text</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the UL width is 100% and then all UL are aligned to the left. How can I center the content into UL? I must have that style for the LI, so I need a UL with fitting to the content.

Comment: Added css tag, since this question is relevant to styling

Comment: Can you have a fixed width on the `UL` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove that `"float:left"` from your li code because `"display:inline"` is itself do that job for you which you want with `"float:left"`.

Comment: The LI tag also have a image background and the only way to get this background working is using float:left;

Comment: U mean, without using "float:left" the background images can not be displayed in "li"?

To the best of my knowledge, it works fine without using floats also. And in your requirement, if u don't remove that "float:left", then I think it can't be achieved.

Comment: "display:inline" removes the bullet for me

Answer (score 1):

A `margin:auto` style on the `<table>` should work. And you don't need `align="center"` on the `<td>`. Try this:

```
<table style="margin:auto">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li style="float:left;display:inline">Some text</li>
                <li style="float:left;display:inline">Other text</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply display:inline to the ul instead of the li.

What is the reason you're applying it to the li anyway? It seems unnecessary because they are floated, but perhaps there is another reason.